# C - Generic vector library

Tags: performance, c, generics, vectors, macros

I'm quite new to C, and I decided to create a generic vector library. Here is the code:

```
#ifndef VECTOR_H
#define VECTOR_H

#define DEFAULT_CAPACITY 10
#define EXPAND_RATIO 1.5

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

enum error {
    NO_ERROR,
    INDEX_ERROR,
    KEY_ERROR,
    NULL_POINTER_ERROR,
    MEMORY_ERROR
};

#define VECTOR_NEW(vec_name, type)                                           \
    /* a resizable array */                                                  \
    struct vec_name {                                                        \
        size_t length;                                                       \
        size_t capacity;                                                     \
        type* items;                                                         \
    };                                                                       \
                                                                             \
    /* initializes a vector with a specific capacity */                      \
    enum error init_##vec_name##_c(struct vec_name* vec, size_t capacity) {  \
        if (!vec)                                                            \
            return NULL_POINTER_ERROR;                                       \
                                                                             \
        vec->length = 0;                                                     \
        vec->capacity = capacity;                                            \
        vec->items = malloc(capacity * sizeof(*vec->items));                 \
                                                                             \
        return (vec->items) ? NO_ERROR : MEMORY_ERROR;                       \
    }                                                                        \
                                                                             \
    /* initializes a vector with the default capacity */                     \
    static inline enum error init_##vec_name(struct vec_name* vec) {         \
        return init_##vec_name##_c(vec, DEFAULT_CAPACITY);                   \
    }                                                                        \
                                                                             \
    /* frees the memory allocated for the vector */                          \
    static inline enum error free_##vec_name(struct vec_name* vec) {         \
        if (!vec)                                                            \
            return NULL_POINTER_ERROR;                                       \
        free(vec->items);                                                    \
        vec->items = NULL;                                                   \
        return NO_ERROR;                                                     \
    }                                                                        \
                                                                             \
    /* adds an item to the end of the vector */                              \
    enum error append_##vec_name(struct vec_name* vec, type item) {          \
        if (!vec)                                                            \
            return NULL_POINTER_ERROR;                                       \
        if (vec->length >= vec->capacity) {                                  \
            vec->capacity *= EXPAND_RATIO;                                   \
            vec->items =                                                     \
                realloc(vec->items, vec->capacity * sizeof(vec->items));     \
            if (!vec->items)                                                 \
                return MEMORY_ERROR;                                         \
        }                                                                    \
        vec->items[vec->length++] = item;                                    \
        return NO_ERROR;                                                     \
    }                                                                        \
                                                                             \
    /* removes and item from the vector at a specified index (-1 as an index \
     * is pop back)                                                          \
     */                                                                      \
    static inline enum error pop_##vec_name(struct vec_name* vec,            \
                                            size_t index, type* item) {      \
        if (!vec)                                                            \
            return NULL_POINTER_ERROR;                                       \
        if (vec->length <= index)                                            \
            return INDEX_ERROR;                                              \
        if (item)                                                            \
            *item = vec->items[index];                                       \
        const size_t block_size = (vec->length - index - 1) * sizeof(type);  \
        memmove(&(vec->items[index]), &(vec->items[index + 1]), block_size); \
        --vec->length;                                                       \
        return NO_ERROR;                                                     \
    }                                                                        \
                                                                             \
    /* sets an existing vector index to a specifid item */                   \
    static inline enum error set_##vec_name(struct vec_name* vec,            \
                                            size_t index, type item) {       \
        if (!vec)                                                            \
            return NULL_POINTER_ERROR;                                       \
        if (vec->length <= index)                                            \
            return INDEX_ERROR;                                              \
        vec->items[index] = item;                                            \
        return NO_ERROR;                                                     \
    }                                                                        \
                                                                             \
    /* applies the given function pointer to every item in the vector */     \
    static inline enum error map_##vec_name(struct vec_name* vec,            \
                                            void(func)(type*)) {             \
        if (!vec)                                                            \
            return NULL_POINTER_ERROR;                                       \
        for (size_t i = 0; i < vec->length; ++i)                             \
            func(&vec->items[i]);                                            \
        return NO_ERROR;                                                     \
    }                                                                        \
                                                                             \
    /* places the item at a specifed index in the`value` parameter */        \
    static inline enum error get_##vec_name(struct vec_name* vec,            \
                                            size_t index, type* value) {     \
        if (!vec)                                                            \
            return NULL_POINTER_ERROR;                                       \
        if (vec->length <= index)                                            \
            return INDEX_ERROR;                                              \
        *value = vec->items[index];                                          \
        return NO_ERROR;                                                     \
    }

#endif  // VECTOR_H
```

Here is how it is used:

```
#include "veclib.h"

VECTOR_NEW(vector_int, int)

int main() {
    struct vector_int vec;
    init_vector_int(&vec);

    for (size_t i = 0; i <= 10; ++i) append_vector_int(&vec, i);
}
```

I'm unsure if my code is elegant, fast, etc. Thanks!

Comment: Is `VECTOR_NEQ` a typo?

Comment: map is possibly a bad name - it's usage across other modern libraries tends to be map(from, to, convFunc)

Comment: Need to look at boundary conditions.. for instance pop seems like it might have an issue if there's only 1 element left.  And minor spelling issue in `removes and item` _and_ should be _an_.

Comment: Presumably the error return code is important - so why in your example aren't you using it?  (possibly that will show an issue with usage??).

Comment: VECTOR_NEW doesn't create a "new" vector - it just defines the type/methods - so maybe should be VECTOR_DEFINE_TYPE? Or something more like what it is.  And what if init_vector_int isn't called - everything breaks (it assumes that it has been init'd properly) ... is there a way you can setup so by default if it's not init'd properly it catches that and tells the user.

Comment: After free_ the rest of the structure refers to things that are wrong (i.e. old size, etc. still there).  Same issue as init_vector / but in reverse.

Comment: Have a reserve method / or similar - because user should be able to manage memory.  Also `include "veclib.h"` so `#ifdef _VECLIB_H`

Comment: @vnp -- Yes, it is.

Comment: Do you agree with the edit?

Comment: @vnp -- Yep, I do

Comment: @MrR -- Would an `_initialized` field for the vector be a good idea to make sure the vector is properly initialized? Or maybe a macro?

Comment: @xilpex have to allow for these issue (default initialization) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597405/what-happens-to-a-declared-uninitialized-variable-in-c-does-it-have-a-value.  i.e. on the stack you don't know if it's initialized or not... a static you can rely on defaults to 0 - so don't need an `_initialized` because (`length == capacity == items == 0`).

Comment: @xilpex also see if there's any ideas here https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/101816/generic-vector-implementation-in-c-using-macros

Answer (score 1):

### Naming

Very good comments and documentation. I had a clear picture of what you were trying to accomplish.

Instead of giving your users the ability to create any `##vec_name`, I would consider, *eg* `vec_##name`, to give my vector types a naming consistency.

It is possible that not all of your functions are used; this generally leads well-meaning compilers to emit a warning for `static` functions. I received this good advice, [silencing unused static functions by using them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43843169/2472827).

### Allocation

`append##vec_name` converts to `double` and back. This might work for the `DEFAULT_CAPACITY` 10, but printing off,

```
printf("append " #vec_name " capacity %lu -> ", vec->capacity); \
vec->capacity *= EXPAND_RATIO; \
printf("%lu\n", vec->capacity); \
```

If it's 0 or 1, it gets stuck in undefined behaviour,

```
append vec_foo capacity 1 -> 1
```

On my computer, the code works for one re-allocation, then it segmentation faults. It's easier to debug when the memory allocation is in one function instead of both `init_##vec_name##_c` and `append_##vec_name`. A feature of `realloc`,

> If ptr is a null pointer, realloc() shall be equivalent to malloc()
> for the specified size.

allows easily moving functions around to get one-point-of-failure, for example,

```
static enum error resize_##vec_name(struct vec_name* vec, size_t min_capacity) { \
    size_t new_capacity; \
    type* new_items; \
    if (!vec) \
        return NULL_POINTER_ERROR; \
    for (new_capacity = vec->capacity > DEFAULT_CAPACITY \
        ? vec->capacity : DEFAULT_CAPACITY; \
        new_capacity < min_capacity; new_capacity *= EXPAND_RATIO);\
    if (vec->capacity >= new_capacity) \
        return NO_ERROR; \
    new_items = realloc(vec->items, new_capacity * sizeof *new_items); \
    if (!new_items) \
        return MEMORY_ERROR; \
    vec->items = new_items; \
    vec->capacity = new_capacity; \
    return NO_ERROR; \
} \
```

Then this simplifies `init_##vec_name##_c`,

```
vec->length = 0; \
vec->capacity = 0; \
vec->items = 0; \
return resize_##vec_name(vec, capacity); \
```

and `append_##vec_name`,

```
if((e = resize_##vec_name(vec, vec->length + 1)) != NO_ERROR) \
    return e; \
vec->items[vec->length++] = item; \
```

### Functions

Viewed as a state machine, your programme has some invalid states. Suggest in `free##vec_name`,

```
vec->capacity = vec->length = 0; \
```

In `pop##vec_name`, the documentation says that -1 is the back, which is useful, kind of like Python, but I don't it see the code.

In `set##vec_name`, you use an assignment. For large types, this might mean a lot of copying. It would be faster to construct it in place; this is kind of like the difference between `push_back` and `emplace_back` in `C++`.

The value of `vec` is `const` in `set_##vec_name`, `map_##vec_name`, and `get_##vec_name`. This might help the compiler to more aggressively optimise, and may be important self-documentation: it's a statement that vector's topology will not change.

Typo: specified. `init_##vec_name##_c` and `append_##vec_name`, I assume you also meant to make them `static`.

### Errors

Your abstraction of errors and passing them on to the user is great. `stdio.h` is not needed and not even included.

`enum error` has a high probability of namespace clashes with other headers. You might want to use the facilities given in `errno.h` instead of inventing your own. Instead of having to return one of several values, one returns a bit — a null value or a flag — telling your users to check `errno`. This will also simplify passing errors from the standard library because you can just pass on the error to the caller instead of making up a new error.

It depends on what the use case for this is, but I would consider making programming errors `assert` instead of dynamic checks, (*eg* `NULL_POINTER_ERROR`.) I've found that this frees a lot of cases from your testing and verification.

Comment: *In `set##vec_name`, you use an assignment. This limits the vectors to assignable types. I would question the use of this function at all.* -- Could you please elaborate on this?

Comment: I edited that -- _eg_ a `struct` or `union` is not going to be assignable. A more general `memset(...sizeof item...)` like one did for the constructor is more general.

Comment: On the `restrict` keyword -- Would `static inline enum error pop_##vec_name(struct vec_name* restrict vec, size_t index, type* restrict item)` be a good idea (I haven't used `restrict` before)?

Comment: I think it might help, see [usage of restrict](https://stackoverflow.com/a/745877/2472827), but it affects pointers of compatible types.

Comment: I have seen that, but is my usage above a good idea?

Comment: I've replaced the a more general statement by more a more concrete review now that I've played with it. I don't think you have any functions where `restrict` could be beneficial, but maybe I'll save that for someone who knows more; it might be an array of arrays? `struct` is assignable, my mistake -- updated.